# Oracle no index for function calls in sql query

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a table with name t(abc varchar2(50),xyz varchar2(50), ..etc) and index enabled on column abc. Oracle uses the index for `userfunction(a)` which takes long time. This is a dynamic query formed can have another conditions that must use index on abc so I don't want to use no_index hint.

```
select *from t 
where
userfunction(a) = 0
and exists (select 1 from tab where t.abc='' ...etc)
and ..etc
```

I tried to re-write the query with nested query by moving the function to nested query, but oracle is re-writing and still executing `userfunction(a)` at the first and the query is taking long time.

```
select *from (
    select *from t
    where
    and exists (select 1 from tab where t.abc='' ...etc)
    ..etc
    )
userfunction(a) = 0
```

Also tried using WITH clause but no luck.

Any idea of oracle not to use index for user function calls or certain condition in where clause?

Comment: what is userfunction ?

Comment: `userfunction(a)` or `userfunction(abc)`? I don't think the problem is that Oracle uses an index to access data. But maybe it could make use of a more appropriate index. It would help to see the whole query. Also: is `userfunction` deterministic (i.e. will I get the same result for the same value, if I call it, say, next year)?

Comment: it is userfunction(abc). it is not deterministic. Basically it is very costly function, I want this to be called only at the last and clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not logically consistent:  you reference table t and tab, but only desribe t.  Assuming you meant t when you wrote tab, I can't see why you need the exists clause with a sub-query.  EXISTS will just return TRUE when the expression in the subselect evaluates to TRUE; so why not just use that expression in the main query on t?